# DRF Imagefield upload responds with html template instead of JSON

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm working with Django Rest Framework 3.5.4 Django 1.9 python 3.5 and Angular 1.4.5.  I'm having an issue where I can upload/post to an image endpoint but the response I get is the DRF template instead of the JSON that I was expecting.

**models.py**

```
class BeforeImage(models.Model):
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job, related_name='before_images')
    before_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', default='images/no-image.jpg')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.pk

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'before_images'
```

**serializers.py**

```
class BeforeImageSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    before_image = ImageField(
        max_length=None, allow_empty_file=False, use_url=True)

    class Meta:
        model = BeforeImage
        fields = ('id', 'job', 'before_image')
```

**views.py**

```
class BeforeImageViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = BeforeImage.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BeforeImageSerializer
```

**Payload**

```
------WebKitFormBoundarybB5wAXF1Q6ZaG9pB Content-Disposition: form-data; name="job" 10 ------WebKitFormBoundarybB5wAXF1Q6ZaG9pB Content-Disposition: form-data; name="before_image"; filename="Screen Shot 2017-04-10 at 11.44.24 PM.png" Content-Type: image/png ------WebKitFormBoundarybB5wAXF1Q6ZaG9pB--
```

**content-type**

```
Content-Type:multipart/form-data;
```

Comment: Can you post the data that you are sending from angular to django API?

Comment: @SijanBhandari I just updated the question with the payload

Comment: Have you tried :  JSON.stringify to send the data?
I have once used following in my code for sending post request from angular to Django API:

```$http({```
   method: 'POST',
   url: '/contact/',
   data:  JSON.stringify({test: json})
```});```

Comment: it's sending multipart form-data  and JSON.Stringify converts a json object to a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's content negotiation and the preferred renderer when submitting forms is HTML because that's consistent with browsers.

If you want a JSON response, you should make sure your request set the headers so it gets JSON. In other words, you need to set the `Accept` headers to `application/json`